# Cubic root of large number

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to identify the cubic root of a large number. I found a solution which works for smaller numbers, but not in this case:

```
require 'openssl'
q = OpenSSL::BN::generate_prime(2048)
ti = q.to_i        #=> 3202718747...
ti3 = ti ** 3      #=> 328515909...
m = ti3 ** (1/3.0) #=> Infinity
```

I was hoping to see `m` = the original output of `ti`. Yes, this is a part of a Matasano challenge. I've put a lot of effort into not seeking help thus far, but I've reached a point where it's just a "how do I do something otherwise simple, in Ruby". Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the Matasano challenge is, but what comes to mind is [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method)

The wikipedia page on [Cube Roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root#Numerical_methods) also suggests using Newton's Method

Comment: Thanks for that. That looks like a heck of a lot more code and I was hoping for a one-liner - but if it works it works. I'll see if I can succeed in implementing it.

Comment: You can probably squeeze it into a couple lines. It looks a lot more complicated than it is!

Answer (score 1):

In ruby operations on integers automatically get promoted to bignums (arbitrary precision integers), so you never get an overflow.

The same is not true of floating point operations: you end up with infinity because raising to the power 1/3 is a floating point operation and the first thing it does is try to convert your number to a float. The biggest number a float in ruby can represent is about 10^308 whereas your number is probably around the 10^1800 mark, so it bails out and returns Infinity

Ruby has a `BigDecimal` class for this. You might therefore be tempted to do

```
BigDecimal.new(ti3) ** (1/3.0)
```

This gives a wildly wrong answer for me - I suspect because (1/3.0) is a float, so only approximately 1/3

```
BigDecimal.new(ti3) ** Rational(1,3)
```

On the other hand produces the correct result for me (with negligible error). `Rational` is Ruby's class for representing fractions in an exact manner. In ruby 2.1 you can shorten this to

```
BigDecimal.new(ti3) ** (1r/3)
```

The docs do say that only integer exponents are supported but this seems to be a hangover from the ruby 1.8 days

Comment: You're absolutely right, and I actually tried several of these options before posting.

Answer (score 1):

The following code was put forward based on the two pieces of advice given.

```
def nthroot(n, a, precision = 1e-1024)
  x = a
  begin
    prev = x
    x = ((n - 1) * prev + a / (prev ** (n - 1))) / n
  end while (prev - x).abs > precision
 x
 end
```

It was based on an implementation of Newton's method which dealt with floats, but also just returned infinity. This version deals with integers only, but works for large integers.

Of course, an nthroot, may be called with n = 3.